# Who is in the middle of the Marvel's Avengers Vol. 3 #38 cover?

Tags: marvel, comics, avengers, cover-art

The Wikipedia page for [Marvel's Avengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_%28comics%29) comics uses the following cover for the main illustration:

[image: Marvel's Avengers Vol. 3, #38 Cover showing a group of Avengers all stood together including Iron Man, Thor, Cap, Scarlet Witch and more]

This comes from *Avengers Vol. 3*, Issue 38, which according to the [Marvel Fandom Database entry](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_3_38) has a fairly long list of featured characters (significantly more than appear on the cover).

I'm in the process of updating the caption on that Wikipedia page, which up until earlier today was missing identifiers for several of the depicted characters. The one character I can't definitively identify is whoever's standing near the middle, with their face showing between Captain America and the Scarlet Witch:

[image: Unknown face on cover: a darker skinned sterned face character with slightly silver hair]

Here's the list of featured male characters who I haven't already identified on the cover (in order of my top guesses):

- Living Lightning (Miguel Santos)
- Wonder Man (Simon Williams)
- Black Knight (Dane Whitman)
- Quasar (Wendell Vaughn)

Perhaps someone who has access to the book can clarify who that last character is on the cover?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Evident from his glowing eyes and silvery hair, it's Simon Williams aka [Wonder-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Simon_Williams_(Earth-616))

[image: Close up of the man in question from the question, dark skinned, silver hair and glowing red eyes]
 <sub>*Avengers Vol. 3, Issue 38 cover; click image to enlarge*</sub>

He appears later as well in the same issue:

[image: Wonder-Man half a glow with his red eyes with Captain Marvel in the background drinking a cup of tea]
 <sub>*Avengers Vol. 3, Issue 38 Page 5; click image to enlarge*</sub>

Comment: Oh yeah, I think you're right. The image on Wikipedia was so reduced the glowing eyes weren't visible to me.